# getting overflow exception while intiliazing in c# constructor

Tags: c#-4.0

i have a class like this

```
public class Menu
    {
        public int MenuID { get; set; }
        public string MenuName { get; set; }
        public string LinkAddress { get; set; }
        public Menu[] menu;
}
```

while i am trying to intilize in the constructor as follows i get an overflow exception error

```
 public Menu() {
            Menu[] menu = {
                              new Menu { MenuID = 1, MenuName = "Home", LinkAddress = "home/index" } 
                              , new Menu { MenuID = 2, MenuName = "Gallery", LinkAddress = "Gallery/index" } 
                              , new Menu { MenuID = 3, MenuName = "Academics", LinkAddress = "Academics/index" } 
                              , new Menu { MenuID = 4, MenuName = "Blog", LinkAddress = "Blog/index" } 
                              , new Menu { MenuID = 5, MenuName = "Login", LinkAddress = "Login/index" } 
                              , new Menu { MenuID = 6, MenuName = "UserLogin", LinkAddress = "UserLogin/index" } 
                              , new Menu { MenuID = 7, MenuName = "ForgotPassword", LinkAddress = "ForgotPassword/index" } 
                          };
        }
```

i also tried to intialize myvariable

```
public Menu[] menu;
```

in the constructor but i was not able to intialize it. can anyone tell me what exactly am i doing wrong. I thought constructor is used to intialize variables but i am not able to intiliaze it.
thank you for your help.

Comment: StackOverflowException != OverflowException.  Your default constructor creates Menu items with the default constructor.  Which creates Menu items with the default constructor.  Which creates Menu items with the default constructor.  Which creates Menu items with the default constructor.  Which creates Menu items with the default constructor.  Which creates Menu items with the default constructor.... Kaboom!   Consider that you need *two* classes,  a Menu and a MenuItem class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are made a circular reference when declaring an array of a class inside the class:

```
 public Menu[] menu;//<-- declaring inside Menu class produces circular refernce
```

thus an overflow exception

Use a method instead, e.g:

```
public void InitMenu()
        {
            this.menu = new Menu[]{
                                new Menu { MenuID = 1, MenuName = "Home", LinkAddress = "home/index" }
                              , new Menu { MenuID = 2, MenuName = "Gallery", LinkAddress = "Gallery/index" }
                              , new Menu { MenuID = 3, MenuName = "Academics", LinkAddress = "Academics/index" }
                              , new Menu { MenuID = 4, MenuName = "Blog", LinkAddress = "Blog/index" }
                              , new Menu { MenuID = 5, MenuName = "Login", LinkAddress = "Login/index" }
                              , new Menu { MenuID = 6, MenuName = "UserLogin", LinkAddress = "UserLogin/index" }
                              , new Menu { MenuID = 7, MenuName = "ForgotPassword", LinkAddress = "ForgotPassword/index" }
                          };
        }
```

and consume as:

```
Menu m = new Menu();
            m.InitMenu();
            m.menu=..;//<--acces your array
```

Comment: well i want to intilize public Menu[] menu variable, how can i do that

Comment: declare it in the class that consumes it

Comment: is there no way where i an intilize the variable while i create an object of Menu class...thanks